# Vue.js Computed Property Filtering

Tags: javascript, promise, vue.js

I have a Vue.js computed property as follows.

```
odds() {
    if(this.course && this.time && this.runner) {
      let race = this.data.events.runners.filter(item => item.course === this.course && item.time === this.time)
      let runner = race[0].data.filter(item => item.name === this.runner)
      return runner[0].odds
    } else {
      return false
    }
}
```

Although it returns the expected value I think it looks dirty. Can any one suggest best way to write this code.

Sample JSON is as follows.

```
{
"courses": [{
    "type": "horses",
    "course": "Exeter"
}],
"runners": [{
    "course": "Exeter",
    "time": "14:10",
    "data": [{
        "number": "1",
        "name": "White Lilac",
        "odds": "6\/1"
    }, {
        "number": "2",
        "name": "Sauvignon",
        "odds": "5\/1"
    }, {
        "number": "3",
        "name": "Foxy Lass",
        "odds": "33\/1"
    }, {
        "number": "4",
        "name": "Hot Ryan",
        "odds": "8\/1"
    }, {
        "number": "5",
        "name": "Arqalina",
        "odds": "11\/8"
    }, {
        "number": "6",
        "name": "Presenting Lucina",
        "odds": "14\/1"
    }, {
        "number": "7",
        "name": "Persistantprincess",
        "odds": "12\/1"
    }, {
        "number": "8",
        "name": "Windy Bottom",
        "odds": "20\/1"
    }, {
        "number": "9",
        "name": "Shotgun Sally",
        "odds": "33\/1"
    }, {
        "number": "10",
        "name": "Rule The Ocean",
        "odds": "9\/1"
    }, {
        "number": "11",
        "name": "Avithos",
        "odds": "12\/1"
    }, {
        "number": "12",
        "name": "Monet Moor",
        "odds": "16\/1"
    }]
}]}
```

I would like to know if there is a much better way to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Can you provide some more context about what this code is supposed to be doing? Also what is `this.course`, `this.time` and `this.runner` ?

Comment: @SimonForsberg this property returns the odds of the horse when 3 select boxes Course, Race time and Runner are selected. Basically i want to return the odds of the selected runner in the Runner select box.